# How does the .env file stay hidden/secret?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

How does the .env file stay hidden/secret when in the same dir as settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py? Should I do something additional to keep my env variables hidden? I will be deploying AWS elastic beanstalk and want to make the code open source. I have the (environment variables ) set like:

**.env**

```
DEBUG=on
SECRET_KEY=blah123456
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=blah123456
```

**Settings.py**

```
import os
import environ

env = environ.Env(
    #set casting
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
# read .env file 
environ.Env.read_env()

MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = env('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: Settings, URLs and wsgi are not visible either, so I don't know what your question is.

Comment: ** Let me rephrase > I want to keep my keys hidden and make the project open source. I was simply asking from a technical standpoint of how it works to keep things hidden? Do you understand?

Comment: The point is that the env file would not be in the same repo.

Comment: So I could use .gitignore when I commit to just ignore that file? Also, thank you for your time and for responding.

Comment: .gitignore is oneway, however double check your commit.

Comment: Okay, will do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you can put the .env in git ignore but I will suggest two more things.

- Load Environment variable from the system config in Elasticbeanstalk.
- or If still want to use dotenv then will suggest putting `.env.template` with an example values so one should know the required ENV.

**Configuring Environment Properties**

> Environment properties appear in the Elastic Beanstalk console under
>   Software Configuration.
>
> To configure environment properties in the Elastic Beanstalk console
>
> Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.

- Navigate to the management page for your environment.
- Choose Configuration.
- In the Software configuration category, choose Modify.
- Under Environment properties, enter key-value pairs.
- Choose Apply.

> You can use Elastic Beanstalk configuration files to set environment
>   properties and configuration options in your source code. Use the
>   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment namespace to define
>   environment properties.

```
#Example .ebextensions/options.config

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    API_ENDPOINT: www.example.com/api
```

then u can use

```
import os
endpoint = os.environ['API_ENDPOINT']
```

[elasticbeanstalk-environments-cfg-softwaresettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!